# How to write a NSString array object in one go?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

My problem is that I know NSString may used as an array and in my code I wrote it as such:

```
NSString *loadBackground[3];
loadBackground[0] = @"background1";
loadBackground[1] = @"background2";
loadBackground[2] = @"background3";
```

Is it possible to write the same code in one line instead of 4 lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use NSArray instead of c-arrays

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"background1", @"background1" , @"background1", nil];
```

accessing a string:

```
NSString *aString = [array objectAtIndex:1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an NSArray instead:

```
NSArray *bgs = [@"bg1,bg2,bg3" componentsSeparatedByString:@","]; // => [@"bg1", @"bg2", @"bg3"];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
NSString *st11[3]={@"hai",@"hai1",@"hai2"};
NSLog(@"%@,%@,%@",st11[0],st11[1],st11[2]);
```

Comment: Gah you beat me to it! But yes, that's the solution if he really wants it over `NSArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're not using `NSArray`, but if you *really* want to do it you can do:

```
NSString *loadBackground[3] = {@"background1", @"background2", @"background3"};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *strs[3]={@"str1",@"str2",@"str3"};
```

use: `strs[0];`